# backtrack 5 r3 freeze when trying to run it from usb

Tags: backtrack-linux

I had tried to run **backtrack 5 r3** from usb and i faced this problem at the end of the black screen:
"---[ end trace .... ]---

kernel panic - not syncing:attempted to kill init!

[sda] attached scsi disk"
,where backtrack freezes and wont response.

I tried to reinstall it,but nothing changed.

I have formatted usb to **fat32** and have used **unetbootin**.

Comment: Welcome to SO :) Please don't use an image (moreover a photo) to post your shell output but edit your question and copy/paste your output inside it.

Comment: ok
i will,thanks alot.

Comment: Phoenix,

You can run Backtrack from with particular kernel settings...

Comment: thanks Daniel,please tell me how?

Answer (score 0):

however,after two days searching on the internet,the only way to use backtrack on usb is use the latest version of backtrack( kali linux https://www.kali.org/)
I knew that when this message appreared "cannot load a ramdisk with an older kernel image",that means the computer hardware Does not match with the backtrack version.
this problem can exist on many computers,not all of them.